# Is there a way to make Visual Studio 2010 remember how I like to view a xaml file?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, xaml

When I open a xaml, I prefer to have the page/control on the right, and the xaml on the left (split vertically).  Currently I have to adjust this each time I open a new xaml because it defaults to splitting them horizontally (page on top, xaml on bottom).  Is there a way to preserve my desired layout?

Comment: +1 praying there is an answer to this one, annoys the hell out of me!

Comment: I'm inclined to believe that it doesn't have the ability to do so, unless you go hunting for the file that contains the layout and edit it directly.

Answer (score 3):

> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> XAML -> Miscellaneous -> Default
>   View

This will give you the option to open XAML files in full-code view by default. Sadly there aren't more options.

Comment: I found that answer on the net and it doesn't technically address the problem. It allows you to specify full page view, not how the split view is organised.